# Get outlet params from other outlet

Tags: angular2-routing

I have the following url structure:

`http://localhost:4200/foo/:fooId/(bar:barId//baz:bazId)`

And the following router config:

```
{
    path: 'foo',
    children: [
        {
            path: ':fooId',
            component: fooComponent,
            children: [
                {
                    path: ':fooId',
                    component: FooComponent
                },
                {
                    path: ':barId',
                    component: BarComponent,
                    outlet: 'bar'                
                },
                {
                    path: ':bazId',                
                    component: BazComponent,
                    outlet: 'baz'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If I am at `http://localhost:4200/foo/0/(bar:1//baz:2)`, inside the `BazComponent`, how can I retrieve the `barId` parameter from the `bar` outlet?

Comment: use `$stateParam` service

Comment: you want both param (bar:barId//baz:bazId) at same time?

Comment: @ShaileshLadumor either of them, if I can get one I can get the other. But I think I just figured out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

params: any[] = [];

constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.parent.children.forEach(children =>  {
        this.params.push(children.snapshot.params);
    });
}

ngOnInit() {
    console.log(params);
}

// This returns:
// [
//     { bar: barId },
//     { baz: bazId }
// ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

    constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute){}
    barId:number;

    ngOnInit(){
      // 'bar' is the name of the route parameter
      this.barId = this.route.snapshot.params['bar'];
    }
```

Comment: Returns undefined, remember we are inside the `BazComponent`. This would only work inside `BarComponent`

Comment: try this one -> this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.id = params['bar'];
    });

Comment: that still returns only `bazId`.

Comment: do you need both barId and bazId from same component ?

Comment: only `barId`, if you see my answer I can retrieve both `barId` and `bazId`, but only retrieving `barId` would be ideal.